# parse long to negative number

Tags: java, math, numbers, long-integer

code:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        long t=24*1000*3600;
        System.out.println(t*25);
        System.out.println(24*1000*3600*25);
    }
}
```

This prints :

```
2160000000

-2134967296
```

Why?

---

Thanks for all the replies.

Is the only way to use L after the number?

I have tried the `(long)24*1000*3600*25` but this is also negative.

Comment: If you have found an answer that solved your problem, make sure you vote it as an accepted answer (by clicking the check mark underneath the score).

Comment: Hi hguser. By `(long)24*1000*3600*25` you convert the result, which is `-2134967296`, into a long, which is `-2134967296L`. You could indeed use (long) instead of L but with additional parentheses: `((long)24)*1000*3600*25`. However, L is exactly made for this case, and it's even possible that the compiler generates different byte code: 24L is a literal of type long, while (long)24 is a literal of type int which first needs to be converted to a long (yet hopefully the compiler optimizes that).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To explain it clearly,

```
System.out.println(24*1000*3600*25);
```

In the above statement are actually `int` literals. To make treat them as a `long` literal you need to suffix those with `L`.

```
System.out.println(24L*1000L*3600L*25L);
```

Caveat, a small `l` will suffice too, but that looks like capital `I` or `1`, sometimes. Capital `I` doesn't make much sense here, but reading that as `1` can really give hard time. Furthermore, Even sufficing a single value with `L` will make the result `long`.

Comment: a small `l` looks more like the digit `1`.

Comment: @dogbane: Oh! Yeah, in most programming editors, its more similar to `1`. But I am not that wrong in suggesting that, I suppose. It happens when your font is `Arial`. Try that out, both would be ditto of each other.

Comment: note that only one numbers needs to be `long`; 24L*1000*36000*25 will also work because the final result will be the length of the maximum equation member's length, in this case it's `long`. This is also true in almost every programming languages. Note that sometimes you'll need have a double so you don't loose any bit, ex: (long) (1d * someLong * someLong / someLong)

Answer (score 19):

You reached the max of the `int` type which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or 2^31-1. It wrapped because of this, thus showing you a negative number.

For an instant explanation of this, see this comic:

[image]

Comment: Funny,however I can not understand this comic..:(. But I maybe know the meaning,it show the Data overflow? Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it shows the sheeps count going up until 32,767, then when the overflow occurs the count goes on, but starting from the lower limit. To me the metaphore of the circle helps a lot in understanding this.

Comment: You need to compile in 16 bit mode for that comic to work.  Or use shorts.

Comment: Keep incrementing an int and you pass from Integer.MAX_VALUE to Integer.MIN_VALUE

Answer (score 6):

In the first case you are printing a `long` but in the second, you are printing it as `int`.

And `int` has a range from: -2^31 to 2^31 - 1 which is just below what you are calculating (int max: 2147483647 you: 2160000000) so you overflow the int to the negative range.

You can force the second one to use `long` as well:

```
System.out.println(24L*1000*3600*25);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should suffix the numbers with 'l'. Check the snippet below:

```
   public static void main(String[] a){
        long t=24*1000*3600;
        System.out.println(t*25);
        System.out.println(24l*1000l*3600l*25l);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Integral literals are treated as type `int` by default. `24*1000*3600*25` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so overflows and evaluates to -2134967296. You need to explicitly make one of them a `long` using the L suffix to get the right result:

```
System.out.println(24L*1000*3600*25);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do mathematical operations with large numerical values without over flowing, try the BigDecimal class.

Let's say I want to multiply

200,000,000 * 2,000,000,000,000,000,000L * 20,000,000

```
int testValue = 200000000;
System.out.println("After Standard Multiplication = " +
                                                       testValue * 
                                                       2000000000000000000L * 
                                                       20000000);
```

The value of the operation will be -4176287866323730432, which is incorrect.

By using the BigDecimal class you can eliminate the dropped bits and get the correct result.

```
int testValue = 200000000;        
System.out.println("After BigDecimal Multiplication = " +
                              decimalValue.multiply(
                              BigDecimal.valueOf(2000000000000000000L).multiply(
                              BigDecimal.valueOf(testValue))));
```

After using the BigDecimal, the multiplication returns the correct result which is

80000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

```
(int)Long.valueOf("2345678901").longValue();
```

Comment: Can you explain how `(int)` makes sense in your example?