# GWT strange long issue

Tags: gwt, long-integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java long number calculate problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957937/java-long-number-calculate-problem)

I have the following code in my GWt 2.1.0 application:

```
long test = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
```

When I check the value of test in Eclipse debug mode it turns out to be -1702967296 (negative) which seems like an overflow issue but the expected result from the above line (i.e. 2592000000) does not seem to be greater than even an integer range, unless I am completely missing something.

Comment: Sorry I have found the answer in another thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957937/java-long-number-calculate-problem)

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of "1000" is it a long or an integer?

Is the arithmetic being performed with, say, 32 bit integers, overflowing and then the result being cast to a long

Comment: I have found that the numbers are being taken as int literals. thanks